# Unit Test Javascript Web worker . And to mock http calls inside Web Worker

Tags: javascript, http, jasmine, mocking, web-worker

I am new to web worker . I have written a web worker which gets message and reads data on onmessage event and after that it makes an ajax/http call to get data. Once data is returned from ajax/http call it posts message back using postMessage event. 
Now I want to know how to unit test this web Worker  using Jasmine and Karma . I tried testing it but unable to Mock the http call inside web worker. Below is my code. Thanks In advance.

**worker.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';  var startDate, endDate, token, initialized;

var http = {};

/*  Code To make http request - Starts */
http.x = function () {
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    var versions = [
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0",
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0",
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
        "Microsoft.XmlHttp"
    ];

    var xhr;
    for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
            break;
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }
    return xhr;
};

http.send = function (url, callback, method, data, async, headerToken) {
    if (async === undefined) {
        async = true;
    }
    var x = http.x();
    x.open(method, url, async);
    if (headerToken !== null && headerToken !== "") {
        x.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + headerToken);
    }
    x.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (x.readyState === 4 && x.responseText !== "" && x.responseText !== undefined && x.responseText !== null) {
            callback(JSON.parse(x.responseText));
        }
    };
    x.send(data);
};

http.get = function (url, data, callback, async, headerToken) {
    var query = [];
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            query.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]));
        }
    }
    http.send(url + (query.length ? '?' + query.join('&') : ''), callback, 'GET', null, async, headerToken);
};
/*  Code To make http request  - ends */


var postOpenOrdersTile = function (result) {
    if (result) {
        postMessage('<div id="openOrdersTile" class="tileContent">' +result.TotalOpenOrders +'</div>');
    }

};

function run(url) {
    var baseUrl = url;
    var openOrdersTilesUrl = baseUrl + "/DashboardTiles/GetOpenOrderTileValues";
    http.get(openOrdersTilesUrl, createDashboardTileInput(startDate, endDate), postOpenOrdersTile, true, token);
}

var load = function (response) {
    var baseUrl = response.base + response.api;
    run(baseUrl);
}

/* Code To triggere Worker - onmessage */
self.onmessage = function (msg) {
    if (msg.data.baseUrl && !initialized) {
        self.importScripts(msg.data.baseUrl + '/BaseApp/Scripts/moment.js');
        startDate = msg.data.fromDate;
        endDate = msg.data.toDate;
        token = msg.data.token;
        http.get(msg.data.baseUrl + '/CardioDashboard/config.json', '', load, true, '');
    }
};}());
```

**WorkerSpec.js**

```
define([], 

function () {  'use strict'  

 describe('Web Worker : Tiles Sharing web Worker', function () {        .
 var worker, data   ;         

 http = { get: function () { return {} } };
    beforeEach(function () {
        worker = new Worker('path/Worker.js');
        data = {
            baseUrl: "xyz",
            fromDate: '2017-04-13',
            toDate: '2017-04-07',
            token: ''             
        };
        worker.postMessage(data);
    });

    afterEach(function () {

    });


    it('Tests the Webworker', function (done) {
        spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue({});
        spyOn(window, 'postOpenOrdersTile').and.callFake(function () {
            return {};
        });
        worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
            if (e.data) {
                expect(e.data).toBe('<div id="openOrdersTile" class="tileContent">45</div>');                        
            }
            if (triggerCount === 6) {
                done();
            }
        });

    });
});});
```

Comment: What's the output of your test?

Comment: Output was Expected <div id="openOrdersTile" class="tileContent">null</div> to be equal to<div id="openOrdersTile" class="tileContent">45</div>. Since web worker is actually making the http call but our service needs token to be passed in header.Since it is unit test am not passing the actual token.  Since am just testing the web workers behaviour I dont want to make htpp call instead I need to mock the http and return some value I need. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

The reason the output is `<div id="openOrdersTile" class="tileContent">null</div>` is because the argument for `postOpenOrdersTile` is null. I'm not sure if you're really testing anything useful because you have to mock everything. But try mocking the return value of http.get: `{TotalOpenOrders: 45}`.

You can make the Worker an constructor and attach http to it:

```
var Worker = function() {
  this.http = {
    send: function() {
       // do something
    },
    get: function() {
      // do something
    }
  };
}
```

In test:
    `spyOn(worker.http, 'get').and.returnValue({});`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Actually I have some other function which processes the output of http.get data. I have not added it here , sorry my bad. I actually need to mock the http.get function and check all other function which post process my data . Could you please suggest how can I mock http.get in this scenario

Comment: You should be able to mock whatever function that supplies the data for postOpenOrdersTile() using `spyOn(object, 'function').and.returnValue({});`. I would also recommend checking out mocking promises https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2014/12/09/Testing-async-calls-with-Jasmine. Instead of $.defer you can use native Promise.

Comment: Hi, Since am instantiating a new worker instance in my test spec ,it actually triggeres the web worker . So is it possible to  SpyOn the http, get request in Web Worker . I tried doing so but it didn't work. Kindly suggest me if it is possible to spyOn a function inside web worker